# How to use \begin{enumerate} in tabular without using p{size}

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate

I'd like to generate a table, using tabular, that looks like this

```
+-----------------+---------------+
|    header1      |    header2    | <--- header, centered
|1. djkfjsdalfkj  |1. djhfjdhf    |
|2. asdfdsjkfasd  |2. sadhfdsj    | <--- enumeration list
+----------------+----------------+
     .
     .
     .
rest of table like the above
```

But I do not want to use paragraph option to tabular, since
then I would have to specify a size for the width. I do
not want to do this, since I'll process this .tex file with
`latex2html` (l2h), and I do not want the web page to
have fixed width in the browser. (I do not know
how big a window there will be), and I'd like the table
to resize with the window size automatically.

Is there a way to do it, using tabular, and just using 'c'?

(I need to stay with tabular since I know l2h supports
this. If I go to fancy table packages, it might not
work).

The problem is I can't add `\begin{enumerate}` when I
use 'c'. Hence this does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline

header1
\begin{enumerate}
\item dhfkjdshafkjds
\item hfdsjkhdsjkafsdaf
\end{enumerate}
&
header2
\begin{enumerate}
\item dhfkjdshafkjds
\item hfdsjkhdsjkafsdaf
\end{enumerate}

\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But if I replace `{|c|c|}` above by `{|p{4in}|p{4in}|}`
then it work since one can use `\begin{enumerate}` in a paragraph.

I looked at the examples here
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables
and do not see how to do it.

Question is: **How to use enumeration list in tabular without using p{size}**

thanks

**update:**
As I mentioned above, I'd like the solution to only use tabular. I am using latex2html to process the latex document to convert to HTML. And l2h does not support all the latex packages.

```
Warning: No implementation found for package: tabularx.
Warning: No implementation found for package: paralist..
```

This is the HTML page I get from running the solution below on latex2html

[image]

Comment: You can put the list inside a `varwidth` environment that would shrink to the natural width of its contents. Or you could even use a `minipage`. Is that an option?

Comment: Thanks, but with l2h these things will not work right due to HTML generation limitation it has on what Latex I can use where. I'll just go back to using p{5in} and this allows me to use enumeration lists inside the table cells and l2h can handle that. I'll have to pick a column size I think will not be too large for most monitors. The above size is the MAXIMUM size the table column will extend. User can make column less wide then this size, but not more wide even if the monitor is wider. Most monitors these days are winder than 10 inches I think. So I can make my table 2 columns each is 5 in.

Comment: LaTeX is not "dynamic" like that - it produces a "static" output. If you want things to conform to some variable length, then you need to compile it twice (doesn't help in your case) or use some non-standard setup... which it seems is restrictive to your usage, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions on the web, I stole this one from here: http://www.komascript.de/node/300

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\newcommand*{\sii}{\setdefaultleftmargin{1em}{1em}{1em}{1em}{1em}{1em}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storeenum}{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname
  stored@\@enumctr\endcsname{\expandafter\the\value{\@enumctr}}%
}%
\newcommand*{\restoreenum}{%
  \setcounter{\@enumctr}{\csname stored@\@enumctr\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\sii}X|>{\sii}X|}
  \hline
  \begin{compactenum}
  \item ITEM
  \item ITEM
  \item ITEM
    \storeenum
  \end{compactenum} &
  \begin{compactenum}
    \restoreenum
  \item ITEM
  \item ITEM
  \item ITEM
    \storeenum
  \end{compactenum}\\
  \hline
  \begin{compactenum}
    \restoreenum
  \item ITEM
  \item ITEM
  \item ITEM
    \storeenum
  \end{compactenum} &
  \begin{compactenum}
    \restoreenum
  \item ITEM
  \item ITEM
  \item ITEM
  \end{compactenum}\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've seen the 'many solutions' but as I said, I want to stay with tabular. I am using l2h to process the document, and l2h does not support tabularx. I've just posted the message I get from trying the above with latex2html above.